# Capturing user behaviours such as click events, page visits, search text etc and query and retrieve these data later

Tags: javascript, newrelic, angulartics

How can I capture the following details of user behavior and later on query and get the details back?
The details that I am trying to capture are :
1. Page Visits
2. Click events
3. Search texts
And also be able to query these and retrieve these data programmatically.

**Till now:**
I've used the JavaScript API by including the New Relic Browser's JavaScript snippet for browser monitoring into my app's webpage. 
I am using angulartics-newrelic-insights.
However, so far I am able to only capture the Page Visits only. The click events are not being captured. Am I missing something?

Please guide me how I can achieve these tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to upgrade the subscription to Pro or Pro Trial for this to work.